# Relative position not working with Image component using Next.js 13

Tags: image, next.js

I would like to have responsive images after upgrading to Next.js 13, and the Image component will not accept the "position: relative" style. (layout= has been deprecated) The [Next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#fill) instruct you to use the fill boolean and assign the position in the parent, but that is not working. I attempted to assign the style in the parent and in the actual component but neither is working.

Is this possible, or is there a better way to have responsive images?

The below div tag is inside of a component:

```
   <div className="row">
    {stories.map((story) => {
      return (
        <div key={story.id} className={"col-sm-4 " + styles.imageStyle}>
          <Image
            src={story.image}
            alt={story.alt}
            fill
            className={styles.imageStyle}
          />
        </div>
      );
    })}
  </div>
```

And styles is defined in a module.scss file

```
  .imageStyle {
object-fit: cover;
position: relative;
}
```

inspecting the code shows the Image is overriding the style

```
element.style {
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
left: 0;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
color: transparent;
}

.story-images-block_imageStyle__RCYiz {
object-fit: cover;
*position: relative; (*this has a strikethrough)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
.imageStyle {
    object-fit: cover;
    position: relative!important;
}
```